# jQuery News Ticker - not quite smooth enough

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, I have a nice news ticker that stops on `mouseover` etc... but the animation is slightly jerky - any ideas?

```
var ticker_holder = $('#ticker').get(0);
            var ticker_text = $('#ticker').get(0);
            var ticker_pos = ticker_text.parentNode.offsetWidth;

            var ticker_data = "<strong>Featured: </strong>"
            +"HardCoded, DamnCool, AliveKicking, NinjaGaiden, WikiWord, FeaturedWords...";
            $(ticker_text).html('<marquee scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="20">' + ticker_data + '</marquee>');

            $('#ticker').hover(
                function() { $('marquee', this).get(0).stop();  },
                function() { $('marquee', this).get(0).start(); }
            );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marquee is not recommended tag. Is is nod defined in stadard, avoid using it. Try one of theese plugins:

1. http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html
2. http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm
3. http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/

Comment: I would like to do this without plugins, any more detail? (congrats on your 1k)

Comment: just dig in their's code. i think it is not very complicated.